# Is there a better way to create a 1D array with n number of elements in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

Here is what I did, anyone have a better way of doing it?

[image]

Do they have built-in function to do this? I just started using LabVIEW might have overlooked. Like in MATLAB its just:

```
    x = (0:10-1)
```

and in Python:

```
    x = range(10)
```

Comment: Why do you need a "range?" Typically they would only be used in a for loop and LabVIEW already has that.

Comment: Why are you decrementing followed by an immediate incrementing? You can just get rid of both of those entirely and your code should still function the same. If its because you want to start with value 1, you can do like oysstu below and add a +1 to i inside the loop or just add +1 outside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to create a range, is to do as you've done - but wire the indexing terminal directly and dropping the shift register. There is no built-in way to do this. The only potential gain of that would be to use slightly less space on the diagram.

Edit: As Yair pointed out, there is a built-in way to do this in the form of the ramp pattern. That VI has much more configurability, for example choosing between divide range into N samples or by delta. It does require the full development license however (in the signal processing palette).

[image: Range]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I'll look into the ramp VI

Answer (score 4):

oysstu's solution is certainly good, and it's what I do in the rare cases where I actually need data like this. Another option is the ramp pattern VI which hides somewhere in the palettes and allows some more complex ranges.