# How to map error codes to strings in LabVIEW without a case strucutre?

Tags: design-patterns, error-handling, labview

I'm making a VI that takes an error code and returns a corresponding error message. I could handle this with a case structure but I would rather be able to see all the codes and strings on the same page.

Error codes can be zero, positive, negative or a range of codes with the same error message.

How do I do this?

Comment: The error scheme sounds like a bad design from the start.

Comment: I'm assuming this is to simplify error messages for a UI? The "see all codes on a page" requirement is interesting for sure. We often put our user-defined codes and resulting definitions/UI output into a file and initialize it into a FGV. Then you can just feed the error cluster into the FGV to get a message out, and if you need to change/review the mappings you modify the file. It still uses a case structure in the FGV but its contained, clean, and easy to manage from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own error code text file. Add it to LabVIEW and/or your built app. That gives you one place to look at all your errors. The General Error Handler.vi will be able to display your errors along with built-in library errors. 
Details about creating custom error files are here:
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/lvhowto/def_custom_error_text/

Answer (score 0):

The [General Error Handler](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/glang/general_error_handler/) function has exactly this functionality:

> **user-defined descriptions** is an array of descriptions of user-defined codes. If an incoming error matches one in **user-defined
>   codes**, the VI returns the corresponding description from **user-defined
>   descriptions** in **message.**
>
> **user-defined codes** is an array of numeric error codes you can use to define error codes and messages for your own VIs. The VI searches
>   this array after searching an internal database of error codes. Error
>   codes -8999 through -8000, 5000 through 9999, and 500,000 through
>   599,999 are reserved for you to define your own error messages.

The only issue I can see from your question is that you want to be able to return the same message for a range of codes. In this case you will simply need to use a [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30934016/24447) to create the required arrays of error codes and message, and a Build Array node to concatenate these with your other array constants. If you're going to use the for-loop structure more than once it would be a good candidate for turning into a subVI.